# Group by date and count average in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, reduce

I have a dataset with the timestamp and some params. It looks like that:

```
const resp = [
    {date: 1576098000, responseBot: 0.47, responseManager: 2.0},
    {date: 1576098000, responseBot: 1.50, responseManager: null},
    {date: 1576098000, responseBot: 1.05, responseManager: 2.3},
    {date: 1576108800, responseBot: 1.00, responseManager: 3.3},
    {date: 1576108800, responseBot: 0.60, responseManager: 1.5},
]
...
```

I need to get a grouped result (by date) and count an average of response (bot and manager). Expected result:

```
[
    {date: 1576098000, responseBotAvg: 1.006, responseManagerAvg: 2.15},
    {date: 1576108800, responseBotAvg: 0.8, responseManagerAvg: 2.4}
]
```

What is the best way to achieve this result in pure javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to *group* the array by `date` key using `reduce` method in combination with `concat`.

Then just find out the `average` by dividing the `total sum` to the *number* of elements.

```js
const resp = [
    {date: 1576098000, responseBot: 0.47, responseManager: 2.0},
    {date: 1576098000, responseBot: 1.50, responseManager: null},
    {date: 1576098000, responseBot: 1.05, responseManager: 2.3},
    {date: 1576108800, responseBot: 1.00, responseManager: 3.3},
    {date: 1576108800, responseBot: 0.60, responseManager: 1.5},
]
var result = resp.reduce(function(h, obj) {
  h[obj.date] = (h[obj.date] || []).concat(obj);
  return h; 
}, {});
result = Object.keys(result).map(key => {
  return {
      date: key, 
      responseBotAvg : result[key].reduce((a, b) => a + (b.responseBot || 0), 0)/result[key].length,
      responseManagerAvg : result[key].reduce((a, b) => a + (b.responseManager || 0), 0)/result[key].map(({responseManager}) => responseManager).filter(Boolean).length,
  }
});
console.log(result);
```